# Cannot localize my app (adding a localization language shows no files and adds nothing)

Tags: ios

Basically I can't add Localizations from the project > info > Localizations section.

When i try to do so, i can see the languages and select the one I want. But when the "Choose files and reference language..." screen appears it is completely empty. When i press finish nothing happens as well.

My goal is to localize the app name, so i have to add the InfoPlist.strings files to the languages I need.

If i try just selecting the file and pressing the localize button i get a prompt asking me to select the language, if i try any of the languages shown there i get this message error:

> “Info.plist” couldn’t be moved to “ja.lproj” because either the former
>   doesn't exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn't exist.

I even tried manually adding the .lproj folders and adding the files there but the app name doesn't change. I suspect that it is because the project is configured to look for those in a different place.

This project was originally created with cocos2dx so it came with many things preconfigured, that was a long time ago with an old version of cocos2dx, so i suppose the folder structure has something to do. Still i don't know where to fix to at least be able to add more localizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to first create the "InfoPlist.strings" manually as a file inside the project directory. Then add the file from xcode. Then clicked on localization and select at least 1 language. Then i could add/remove localizations from my project settings.

Comment: "manually as a file inside the project directory" -> where in project directory? which folder?

Comment: It depends on the language you want to add. For example, for english it would be en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings (you have to create the folder itself it it doesn't exist)